# concatenate files with similar names using shell

Tags: shell, unix

I have very limited knowledge of shell scripting, for example if I have the following files in a folder

```
abcd_1_1.txt
abcd_1_2.txt
def_2_1.txt
def_2_2.txt
```

I want the output as `abcd_1.txt, def_2.txt`. For each pattern in the file names, concantenate the files and generate the 'pattern'.txt as an output

```
patterns list <-?
for i in patterns; do echo cat "$i"* > "$i".txt; done
```

I am not sure how to code this in a shell script, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in abcd_1 def_2
do
    cat "$i"*.txt > "$i".txt
done
```

The above will work in any POSIX shell, such as dash or bash.

If, for some reason, you want to maintain a list of patterns and then loop through them, then it is appropriate to use an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
patterns=(abcd_1 def_2)
for i in "${patterns[@]}"
do
    cat "$i"*.txt > "$i".txt
done
```

Arrays require an advanced shell such as bash.

### Related Issue: File Order

Does it the order in which files are added to abcd_1 or def_2 matter to you?  The `*` will result is lexical ordering.  This can conflict with numeric ordering.  For example:

```
$ echo def_2_*.txt
def_2_10.txt def_2_11.txt def_2_12.txt def_2_1.txt def_2_2.txt def_2_3.txt def_2_4.txt def_2_5.txt def_2_6.txt def_2_7.txt def_2_8.txt def_2_9.txt
```

Observe that `def_2_12.txt` appears in the list ahead of `def_2_1.txt`.  Is this a problem?  If so, we can explicitly force numeric ordering.  One method to do this is bash's brace expansion:

```
$ echo def_2_{1..12}.txt 
def_2_1.txt def_2_2.txt def_2_3.txt def_2_4.txt def_2_5.txt def_2_6.txt def_2_7.txt def_2_8.txt def_2_9.txt def_2_10.txt def_2_11.txt def_2_12.txt
```

In the above, the files are numerically ordered.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this (assumes bash, and I didn't test it).

```
declare -A prefix
files=(*.txt)
for f in "${files[@]"; do
    prefix[${f%_*}]=
done
for key in "${!prefix[@]}"; do
    echo "${prefix[$key]}.txt"
done
```